# Can't build yup schema

Tags: formik, yup, vee-validate

I'm trying to build a schema where depending on "goalType", "goalWeight" must be either more than or less than "weight". So if "goalType" is "gain" and "weight" is 40, then "goalWeight" has to be greater than 40.

```
object({
weight: number().min(0).max(200).required(),
goalType: string().default(GoalType.LOOSE),
goalWeight: number()
  .moreThan(0)
  .lessThan(200)
  .required()
  .when("goalType", {
    is: GoalType.LOOSE,
    then: number().lessThan(ref("weight")),
  }),
```

This code gives the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 4, '(keys: string | string[], builder: ConditionBuilder<NumberSchema<number, AnyObject, undefined, "">>): NumberSchema<number, AnyObject, undefined, "">', gave the following error.
  Overload 2 of 4, '(keys: string | string[], options: ConditionConfig<NumberSchema<number, AnyObject, undefined, "">>): NumberSchema<number, AnyObject, undefined, "">', gave the following error.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(295, 5): The expected type comes from property 'then' which is declared here on type 'ConditionConfig<NumberSchema<number, AnyObject, undefined, "">>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed code to

```
object({
weight: number().min(0).max(200).required(),
goalType: string().default(GoalType.LOOSE),
goalWeight: number()
  .moreThan(0)
  .lessThan(200)
  .required()
  .when("goalType", {
    is: GoalType.LOOSE,
    then: (schema) => schema.lessThan(ref("weight")),
  }),
```

and it works now

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).